# How to serve js file as php with nginx?

Tags: nginx

e.g example.com/apple.js loads as a php file apple.js.php

With apache it's:

```
RewriteRule ^apple\.js$ apple.js.php [L]
RewriteRule ^banana\.js$ banana.js.php [L]
```

How do you do the same with nginx?

This is what I've tried and shows 404 error.

```
server {
    server_name www.site.co.uk;

    root /var/www/site/public;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/site.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/site.error.log;

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location ~ /apple.js {
        try_files $uri /apple.js.php;
    }

    location ~ /banana.js {
        try_files $uri /banana.js.php;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

        set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rewrite` rules below would allow these URLs to be served dynamically with PHP

www.site.co.uk/apple.js
www.site.co.uk/banana.js

#### Nginx Server Block

```
server {
  ...

  rewrite ^/apple\.js$  /apple.js.php;
  rewrite ^/banana\.js$ /banana.js.php;

  ...
}
```

#### banana.js.php

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
echo "This is BANANA by PHP";
```

#### apple.js.php

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
echo "This is APPLE by PHP";
```

Comment: Thanks just tried this by renaming to apple.js but it's not parsing the php tags. I would prefer to keep them as .php extension and not have to change security.limit_extensions. Could I use rewrite instead similar to this? https://serverfault.com/a/414188/86582

Comment: Awesome cheers, I do this so I can keep a record of the http referer